# How to make a div fill entire height of outter div and vertically align in the center?

Tags: html, css

I have a similar html to the one bellow (i use external stylesheets but in this example I don't to make it easier to read). 
The "bigger" div dynamically gets multiple lines of text, while the "smaller" always has just one line. However, I want the text in the "smaller" div to vertically align exactly in the middle on the left side of the "bigger" div. I can't use display:table and display:table-cell because I use jquery slidedown function to show the "wrapper" div and that forces the "wrapper" to be display:block.
Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="smaller"style="float: left; min-height: 100%;">
        <p style="vertical-align: middle;">Heading</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bigger" style="float: right;">
        <p>text1</p>
        <p>text2</p>
        <p>text3</p>
     </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please avoid inline styles. You have classes, use them! Also there is no `vertical-align:center`. Take a look here:

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="smaller">
        <p>Heading</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bigger">
        <p>text1</p>
        <p>text2</p>
        <p>text3</p>
     </div>

</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapper{
    display: table;
}

.smaller{
    min-height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 97%;
}
.bigger{
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

You can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` to achieve this.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3tL8vr9r/1/)

Comment: doesn't display:table have issues in certain browsers? Plus you assumed that 'bigger''s height is 100px. I said, the number of lines in 'bigger' is dynamic, so it could be 3 or 10 or 15. The height is always different

Comment: i edited my first comment, can you please read it again? thanks for your help anyways

Comment: @user2395238 You can safely remove `min-height` and `height` from the table-cells, they are just redundant here,

Comment: it works but as soon as I was going to apply it to my code I realized I couldn't. I use jquery slidedown function to show wrapper and that function sets display to block. :(

Comment: Next time you can be more specific when ask a question :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `.bigger` to float, because `.wrapper` relies on it for the height. Try something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xrxacsx/).